# Bcm 4313 issue with Asus 1015e, Brcmsmac, Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, broadcom

I've been hunting around here for about two weeks trying solutions to other people's BCM4313 problems, but none have worked. I was able to solve problems in 12.04 and 12.10 using solutions available through these forums, but in 13.04 nothing has so far worked. I've succeeded in getting back to a point with the brcmsmac driver activated where "wifi is disabled by hardware switch" is my problem.

I'm including lspci and lsmod results here, and also am including the output results from Wild Man's wireless info script.

```
lspci -nnk | grep 4313
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

lsmod brcmsmac
```

Results from the wireless info script:
http://pastebin.com/f6ptr2DD

I have also tried the bcmwl-kernel-source package, but when using it have a different problem.

I am happy/willing to try any suggestion and post results. Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: For me it's the same as for Monad.
If I go to sleep and back wifi is working again right away.
(Asus 1015e - Ubuntu 12.04 / latest updates) *Hardware switch in sleep mode?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to restore bios to factory settings. This is what worked for me on two of my netbooks.

Comment: Can you comment on how this is similar to/different from a fresh install of 13.04?

Comment: I do not know what would happen if you installed a fresh instance of OS. This is a problem that I encountered on my Acer Aspire One D270, after blocking wireless with hardware switch. The only option was to restore factory settings in bios on the abovementioned machine.

Comment: Concerning this wireless card: there is no solution which is 100% workable in my opinion. (The only option that I did not test is actually compiling the drivers from the Broadcom's web site - there is a problem that should be patched to work with new kernels) Thebest solution is to install bcmwl-kernel-source version 5.10, which gives a stable connection but a t low speeds. THe lates broadcom proprietary driver works funny (I didn't succeed to connect to my netbook via ssh from outer network). Brsmsmac driver, that is turned on by default, drops packets frequently, thus is not very reliable.

Comment: Accepting this answer, though the actual solution took a bit more work.

Final solution was:
Fresh install of 13.04
Killed ASUS proprietary drivers
modprobe -r brcmsmac wl
apt-get remove brcmwl-kernel-source
Purchased a nano wireless n usb (Edimax, though I don't know if brand matters here)

Have restarted several times, and Ubuntu keeps trying something each time to make the wireless card work (it's sort of cute how hard it's trying). This often interferes with the USB wireless, but removing whatever module it's using for the attempt has saved me on each reboot so far.

Answer (score 0):

So, this will sound somewhat odd, but I have found a strange workaround by accident. I got the 1015pxd with Ubuntu for my mother, and got the exact same bug when I tried to upgrade to 13.10, but if I hit Fn-f1 (sleep), when the machine wakes up from sleep, the wireless often magically begins to work again until reboot. At which point I can simply repeat the same steps. I've been looking for a better solution 
1)because my mother seems to have a very hard time remembering how to hit the sleep button
2)It is freaky voodoo witchcraft that unnerves the hell out of me. I still have no idea why this works.